# How to make a submenu within a MenuButton in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

I'm trying to add a submenu to my MenuButton and it doesn't seem to be able to accept a Menu as a child. Is it possible to do this, or do I need to use some other kind of menu? My menu is set up like this:

```
class DotMenuButton: MenuButton() {
    item("item 1").action {
        //action 1
    }
    item("item 2").action {
        //action 2
    }
    //here is where I would like a submenu
    menu("sub menu") {
        item("sub menu item 1").action {
            //sub menu action 1
        }
    }
}
```

I am using TornadoFX but if there is a way to do this in plain JavaFX I can adapt it. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Edit:** As of tornadofx 1.7.19-SNAPSHOT the above code now works. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have [committed](https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx/commit/595d8e852e5f1f8a184e0b191c4522567e8bf7e3) support for submenus in `MenuButton`, so your code above will now work with the the latest snapshot release.

Comment: this is a comment, isn't it ;) At least without any further details why it didn't work before and what/how it was fixed now ..

Comment: No, it is an answer. As I said, the framework didn't have this feature, and I have now added that feature.

Comment: @EdvinSyse: I've added a link to your commit; as your change links here, can I impose on you to add any additional detail you think might guide others seeking to use this feature.

Comment: @trashgod Thank you. There really isn't anything to it other than using the code as in the OP's question :) For anyone looking to use this before the next release and if you're not comfortable using a snapshot, you could copy the code from the commit into your own project in the mean time.